# Sending Email with UIViewController Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Sending an email from an UIViewController works well - however, if I try to put it into a category, things do not work anymore. Appreciate any help on this !

Here is the call from my UIViewController :

```
#import "UIViewController+EmailSend.h"
[self sendMailTo:@"myemailadress@xyz.com" :@"this is my subject"];
```

Here is the UIViewController Category :

### UIViewController+EmailSend.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface UIViewController (iKKEmailSend) <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MFMailComposeViewController *mailer;

- (void) sendMailTo :(NSString *)recipient :(NSString*)subject;

@end
```

### UIViewController+EmailSend.m

```
#import "UIViewController+iKKEmailSend.h"

@implementation UIViewController (iKKEmailSend)

@dynamic mailer;

- (void) sendMailTo :(NSString *)recipient :(NSString*)subject {

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    self.mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    // here is where the exception happens - why ?????????????????????????????

    self.mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // setSubject
    [self.mailer setSubject:subject];

    // setToRecipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    [self.mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // setCcRecipients
    // NSArray *toCCRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    // [self.mailer setCcRecipients:toCCRecipients];

    // setBccRecipients:
    // NSArray *toBccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    // [self.mailer setBccRecipients:toBccRecipients];

    // setMessageBody:isHTML
    NSString *emailBody = @"";
    [self.mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:
    // UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myfabolousimage.png"];
    // NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    // [self.mailer addAttachmentData:imageData
    //              mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myfabolousimage.png"];

    [self presentViewController:self.mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {

    } else {
        [self.mailer dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: _"(...) but it’s not possible to declare an additional instance variable in a category."_ (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the MFMailComposeViewController property.

Simply make changes similar to:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];

[self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to mark it as the answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The soul purpose of using **"Categories"** is to add methods and implementation of methods to an existing class without necessarily having the source code. Now think if you want to add some new methods inside **"NSString"** class, you can add your new methods through a category but you can't add iVars to the **"NSString"** class, it's a violation. Hence it's not allowing you to use message view controller that way.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MFMailComposeViewController *mailer;
```

Just declare this property in your view controller and write the implementation in category then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare property in a category,

but you can ObjectiveC runtime, to get and set associated object to instances,
so this solution should work for you.

```
#import "UIViewController+iKKEmailSend.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (iKKEmailSend)

- (void)setMailer:(MFMailComposeViewController *)aMailer
{
     objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "mailer", aMailer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (MFMailComposeViewController *)mailer
{
     return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "mailer");
}

- (void) sendMailTo :(NSString *)recipient :(NSString*)subject {

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    self.mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    // here is where the exception happens - why ?????????????????????????????

    self.mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // setSubject
    [self.mailer setSubject:subject];

    // setToRecipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    [self.mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // setCcRecipients
    // NSArray *toCCRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    // [self.mailer setCcRecipients:toCCRecipients];

    // setBccRecipients:
    // NSArray *toBccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    // [self.mailer setBccRecipients:toBccRecipients];

    // setMessageBody:isHTML
    NSString *emailBody = @"";
    [self.mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:
    // UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myfabolousimage.png"];
    // NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    // [self.mailer addAttachmentData:imageData
    //              mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myfabolousimage.png"];

    [self presentViewController:self.mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {

    } else {
        [self.mailer dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```